# sphero sprk+ isn't discoverable in macbook pro bluetooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth, sphero, gobot.io

I'm trying to connect to Sphero Sprk+ device with gobot.io, like this example: https://gobot.io/documentation/platforms/sprkplus/

The code cannot connect to the device, so I checked in the visible bluetooth devices from Bluetooth Preferences in MacBook, and Sphero isn't listed there.

Sphero is visible from android devices, and is visible from the MacBook via Sphero EDU application, but not directly from the bluetooth console.

What do I miss?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SPRK+ communicates via BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). BLE comes with concept of 'profiles'. There are public (documented, well-known, standard) profiles, like SPP (serial port profile), A2DP (audio profile), etc. If the device supports these profiles, you can see it in system BT preferences.

However, SPRK+ (Sphero) features it's own private communication profile, not known to Apple nor Google.

That's why the EDU application can 'see' the  device, but you cannot find it in BT preferences.